# Sorting with TreeMap and TreeSet not syncronized

Tags: java, json, sorting

I have a problem with sorting two components and don't see why.

I create a SortedMap like this:

```
private static SortedMap<String, String> getMapping( List<LdapMapping> mapping )
  {
    SortedMap<String, String> fieldMapping = new TreeMap<>();
    for ( LdapMapping map : mapping )
    {
      fieldMapping.put( map.getInternalField(), map.getLdapField() );
    }
    return fieldMapping;
  }
```

which also looks good in the generated JSON:

```
  "head": [
    "emailAddress",
    "enabled",
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "name"
  ],
```

afterwards I use this sortedMap to create a second part of the JSON like this:

```
  /**
   * Gets the field values from only ldap.
   *
   * @param entry the entry
   * @param mapping the mapping
   * @return the field values
   */
  private static Map<String, Boolean> getFieldValues( SearchResultEntry entry, Map<String, String> mapping )
  {
    SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>( mapping.keySet() );
    Map<String, Boolean> fields = new HashMap<>();

    for ( String key : keys )
    {
      String ldapField = mapping.get( key );
      String ldapValue = entry.getAttributeValue( ldapField );
      fields.put( ldapValue, Boolean.FALSE );
    }

    return fields;
  }

  ldapUser.setFields( getFieldValues( entry, fieldMapping ) );
  ldapUser.setAction( IMPORT_STATUS_NEW );
```

The second part result get's put into the Object

```
/**
 * The Class LdapUserImpl.
 */
public class LdapUserImpl implements LdapUser
{

  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /** The action. */
  private String action;

  /** The fields. */
  private transient Map<String, Boolean> fields;

  public LdapUserImpl()
  {
    /* nothing special needed */
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public String getAction()
  {
    return action;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public Map<String, Boolean> getFields()
  {
    return fields;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setAction( String action )
  {
    this.action = action;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setFields( Map<String, Boolean> data )
  {
    this.fields = data;
  }

}
```

this part of the JSON then looks like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "action": "New User",
      "fields": {
        "emailAddress": false,
        "lastName": false,
        "firstName": false,
        "enabled": false,
        "name": false
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "New User",
      "fields": {
        "emailAddress": false,
        "enabled": false,
        "firstname": false,
        "name": false,
        "lastname": false
      }
    },
```

As you can see, they don't match, as I want the values in the second part to match with the order of the first part of the JSON like this:

```
  "head": [
    "emailAddress",
    "enabled",
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "name"
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "action": "New User",
      "fields": {
        "emailAddress": false,
        "enabled": false,
        "firstname": false,
        "lastname": false,
        "name": false
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "New User",
      "fields": {
        "emailAddress": false,
        "enabled": false,
        "firstname": false,
        "lastname": false,
        "name": false
      }
    }]
```

*Note: naturally I replaced the real values with the field that get's displayed.*

Where is the Problem with creating the second part?
Is it because I use the SortedSet not correctly in combination with the SortedMap?

Comment: How are you converting to JSON?

Comment: Using standard config for Jackson

Comment: Is it due to the use of `HashMap` that does not preserve the order of the items? Perhaps try using a `LinkedHashMap` and see if you can reproduce the same result

Comment: That's it @SamuelKok ! Could you put your solution in an answer so I can accept it? So stupid I didn't think of that *facepalm of shame*

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers

Comment: Those JavaDoc comments are really bad. How does preceding the name of the class/field with the word "the" add anything useful at all?

Comment: This is work in Progress @Michael , I will add good and explaining JavaDoc once I get the functionality done :) For now it's mostly automatically generated JavaDoc.

Comment: Fair enough. In future I would strip those out when posting to Stack Overflow, in that case.

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `HashMap` in your code which does not preserve the order of the items as mentioned in `HashMap` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the order of the items and it should resolve your issue